# What is the difference between whipped cream and whipping cream?

Tags: cream, whipped-cream

I am searching for accurate stock photos to represent both products. While I really only *need* to figure out what visual differences there are (if any), I would like to understand *why* they are different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whipped cream is whipping cream after it has been whipped.

Whipping cream is just cream with at least 30% fat content (that would be called *Light* Whipping Cream in the US). Heavy Whipping Cream contains at least 36% fat and up to 40% and rarely (in the US) even higher. Until these creams are whipped, they are just liquid. After they are whipped, they're fluffy. A way to know that whipped cream is "done" is that it holds "peaks", like in the first picture. Higher fat cream will thicken more readily, and hold its structure longer. Other countries use different terms for various levels of fat in cream. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cream)

Whipped Cream:

[image: 1]

Whipping cream:

[image: 2]

Comment: In US you also have ready-to-use whipped cream which comes in a can like shaving cream.

Answer (score 3):

Whipping cream is cream that it is possible to whip... cream for whipping.
Take whipping cream, or double cream and whisk it until it stands in peaks and then it is whipped cream.

Comment: If you first add a little icing sugar and vanilla essence and then whip it it will be chantilly cream which is MUCH nicer than plain whipped cream. If you whip really cold cream for too long it will quite suddenly turn into lumps of butter in thin watery buttermilk... disaster!